# Registering Zpanel domain with dottk

Tags: apache, dns, centos, vps, hostname

Simple question here:

How do I set up a dot.tk domain with Zpanel running CentOS on a VPS?

It say I have 2 websites set up under Zpanel: www.test123123123.com and www.tester123123123.com

Let's pretend my IP is 1.1.1.1

How do I have dot.tk point to these domains? I've tried to set up a domain on dot.tk with 1.1.1.1 as the IP. It points to my Zpanel CP. How do I get to the test page?

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup the dot.tk domain in your zpanel to point to the existing test site (page) path.

Answer (score 0):

Goto Zpanel=>Domain Management=>Domains and setup dot.tk. Then goto Zpanel=>Domain Management=>DNS Manager to create default entries for dot.tk.